# Unable to include <ctime> without redefinition of struct TM error

Tags: c++

I've tried the code on Codeblocks and Clion and I'm still getting a redefinition of struct tm error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> // Needed for the true randomization
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int xRan;
    srand( time(0)); // This will ensure a really randomized number by help of time.

    xRan=rand()%15+1; // Randomizing the number between 1-15.
    cout << "Shows a random number between 1-15: " << xRan;

    return 0;
}

When ever I use the library I get the error. Not sure if theres something
```

buggy in the minigw include folder or what. Would deleting all my ide's and reinstalling help? Any ideas maybe why?

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ctime:42:0,
```

from C:\Users\Kelvindavis\CLionProjects\untitled\main.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\include\time.h:172:8: error: redefinition of 'struct tm'
struct tm
        ^
    In file included from 
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\cwchar:44:0,
                 from 
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\bits\postypes.h:40,
    from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iosfwd:40,
    from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ios:38,
    from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38from 
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39from 
    C:\Users\Kelvindavis\CLionProjects\untitled\main.cpp:1:
    c:\mingw\include\wchar.h:87:8: error: previous definition of 'struct tm'
    struct tm {
        ^
    mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
    CMakeFiles\untitled.dir\build.make:61: recipe for target 
    'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed
    CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all' 
    failed
    CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule' 
    failed
    mingw32-make.exe[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
    mingw32-make.exe[1]:  **[CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [untitled] Error 2
    Makefile:117: recipe for target 'untitled' failed

Comment: ***Codeblocks and Clion*** Probably the same compiler used for these 2 different IDEs.

Comment: ***Would deleting all my ide's and reinstalling help?*** I don't think so. Maybe reinstall your compiler instead. Although it is unusual to me that that your toolchain could be broken in this way.

Comment: Show the error message.

Comment: Also remove any code that isn't necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: BTW, the code works fine on ideone. http://ideone.com/s5XbLs

Comment: Compile and link the code from the command line.

Comment: well the error messages says that iostream already included ctime. sounds like ctime doesnt have a guard on it (or time.h).

Comment: Apparently there are two definitions of `struct TM`: one in time.h (at line 172), an one in wchar.h (at line 87). That's definitely a compiler problem, but I don't know enough about your tool chain to tell you what to do. It might be a problem with the installation, or it could be some funky compiler switch.

Comment: hmmm okie dokie, ill try reinstalling the compiler etc. Thanks

Comment: Did reinstalling the (or upgrading) compiler fix the issue?

Comment: No it didnt, I only reinstalled it. It worked fine on my virtual machine though.